# The command prompt is behaving rather weirdly

Tags: command-line

When my C program is relatively simple, something like just a `printf` command, the Command Prompt gives the output fine:

> Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){printf("Get out!");}
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\amish>gcc whatever.c
C:\Users\amish>a
Get out!
```

But when the code is something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
  int is_composite(int a){
    int i;
    int b = 0;
     if(a == 1){b = 2;};
    for(i=2; i<a;i++){
     
    if(a%i ==0){b = 1;
    break;
    };
    
     
   
  }
   return b;}
  int main(){
    int n1;
    int n2;
    int k;
    int l;
    printf("ENTER TWO NUMBERS");
    scanf("%d", &n1);
    scanf("%d", &n2);

    for(k = n1; k<=n2; k++){
      l = is_composite(k);
      if(l == 0){printf("%d ", k);}
    }
   
    return 0 ;}
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\amish>gcc whatever.c
C:\Users\amish>a
Access is denied.
```

I really don't understand why it works with simple codes, but not with complex ones. Or is the reason something else altogether?Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You seem to have way too many } chars in your example. Is this code cut from a bigger project?

Comment: @LPChip I copy-pasted it from the text editor and must have missed a couple.